# Add relation between 2 objects in Parse using JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am using Parse Javascript SDK.

I have 2 classes with the following details:

"Kid" having properties {name, friends}
Here 'friends' is a relation pointing to class Kid's object itself(That is: friend of a kid is another kid)

"Parent" having properties {name, phoneno}

Please assume that following data is in the tables respectively:

**"Kid"**

**ObjId-----------Name ---------- Friends**

FiPUuPV1sG ---- Arjun ----------- Kanav(pointer)

2AiPUuPV1s -----Kanav

3BiPUjsdV1 -----Priya

**"Parent"**

**ObjId ----------Name -------- phoneno**

vzxAEhHuh9 ----- Chintan -------- 123445

abcAEhHuh0 ----- Chitrang ------- 789766

Now i want to be able to add a relation to the kid "Arjun" named Parent, so that it points to the parent "Chintan"

So, for already inserted data in the classes, I want to create relation among the objects.

I have done this-

```
var Kid = Parse.Object.extend("Kid");
var Parent = Parse.Object.extend("Parent");

var q1 = new Parse.Query(Kid);
var arjun = q1.get("FiPUuPV1sG");
var q2 = new Parse.Query(Parent);
var chintan = q2.get("vzxAEhHuh9");
var relation = arjun.relation("parent");
relation.add(chintan);
arjun.save();
```

Please let me know if that is fine!!

Comment: Thanks  everyone.. I resolved it !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add success and error functions to the following

```
var arjun = q1.get("FiPUuPV1sG");
var chintan = q2.get("vzxAEhHuh9");
```

Example:

```
q2.get(obj_id, {
      success: function(fetchedParent) {
              //some functionality
      },
      error: function(object, error) {
              console.log("Failed to get parent: " + error);
      }
 });
```